# Error parsing file

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, vs-code

[image]I am having difficulties deploying reports and dashboards from dev org to another dev org.
After retrieving the metadata ( report folder , dashboard folder, reports and dashboards) i want to deploy by using the command sfdx: deploy source to org.
The error message  I am getting is :

> force-app\main\default\dashboards\dashboarFolderName.dashboardFolder-meta.xml
> Error parsing file: The element type "DashboardFolder" must be
> terminated by the matching end-tag "</DashboardFolder>". (9:7)

I am unble to find what I need to change to overcome this error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The error is giving you the path to the file that's causing the issue. You need to look at that file and see where you're missing an end tag (e.g. if you have a `<DashboardFolder>` start tag, you need a `</DashboardFolder>` end tag as well for it to be valid XML). [Edit] your question to include the contents of that `-meta.xml` file if you're still unsure.

Comment: Another possibility here is that the API version of your file and/or SFDX project is straddling a boundary where Salesforce made changes to how/where metadata is stored or represented. Knowing the API version of your project and of the metadata you're working with is something that would be good to include in your question.

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped. i managed to deploy the folders. Now i am trying to do the same with the reports and dashboard as such but i am getting another error.
Error : Filterlanguage : Invalid value specified: 1. PLease see edited requeest

Comment: i have found the solution  in the meantime. Translation workbench had to be enabled in both orgs.

Comment: This sounds like something you should turn into an answer. Please be sure to include as much detail as you can so that it can help others determine if their situation is similar or not (as well as how to fix the issue if it is similar).